# Laravel : In a many-to-many relationship between A and B, how to get all B's from multiple A's?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In normal many2many tutorials, we're taught how to get all B's from a single specific A by doing `A->B()`. What if you want to get all B's from multiple A's? The first thing that come to mind is using for loop but **what if we don't want to use for loop?**

---

This is my situation : 
I have two models, ConversationsUser and Events. Now I would like to get all Events from multiple ConversationsUser model **without using for loops**.

This is my initial take on the problem :

```
$loginuser = Auth::user();
ConversationsUser::where('user_id','LIKE',$loginuser->id)->events();
```

but it wouldn't work because the events method isn't found.

These are my models and their relationships

**ConversationsUser**

```
public function events(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Events');
}
```

**Events**

```
public function conversations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('ConversationsUser');
}
```

Comment: Use `whereIn` on the `Event` like you were suggested in the other question you posted. That's the way to go.

Comment: There's another way, check my edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
$conversations = ConversationsUser::with('events')->whereUserId($loginuser->id)->get();

$events = $conversations->lists('events')->collapse()->unique();
```

Comment: Also, this function produces a grouped result. I wanted something more like an array of events instead of an array of conversations with events. How do I do that? thanks

Comment: Use has() to return conversations that have events:  ...with('events')->has('events')...  The Laravel docs do a great job of explaining Eloquent: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent.

Comment: @Joseph Unfortunately this is wrong. You can't call `unique` on the collection returned from `fetch` just like that, since it's a collection of arrays (of arrays, not models anymore).

Comment: @deczo - Yep. Thanks for catching that. Updated.

Comment: @JosephSilber no, really, you can't do that using `fetch`. flatten is even worse, it returns flat 1 level array. Eloquent doesn't provide nice and easy solution in this case. Better is just grabbing foreign keys and then using `RelatedModel::whereIn('id', [..]);`

Comment: @deczo - Right again. Updated.

Comment: @JosephSilber can you please explain this part `reduce(function ($result, $events)
{
    return $result + $events;
}, [])`? Thanks!

Comment: @mark - it reduces an array to a single value. Read [the PHP docs on `array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php). The collection's `reduce` method just defers to it.

Comment: Check my answer. This is the easiest way. @Joseph, despite I'm aware you rather know what you do, this time it's not going to work. Like I said `fetch` returns collection of arrays of arrays (not models), so it makes it really hard to get it back to the proper form, where you can call `unique` etc. I don't think it's worth it in this case.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_ - What part of my current code do you think doesn't work?

Comment: You haven't tried that, have you? Try and check the error. Like I said, `fetch` will convert models to arrays so 1: unique won't work, 2: you can't work with Eloquent Models anymore, unless you convert it back.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Actually there is a trick to achieve that easier:

```
$events = null;

ConversationsUser::where('user_id','LIKE',$loginuser->id)
                                      // note the reference
  ->with(['events' => function ($q) use (&$events) {
    $events = $q->get();
  }])->get();

$events;            // all related models with `->pivot` attached (possible dups)
$events->unique();  // unique related events
```

**con**: it will run additional query

**pro**: it's pretty easy to use

---

The best and easiest thing to do is simple `whereIn`.

Depending on the relation type you might need a join, like in this case (for brevity I use short variable names):

```
$convUsers = ConversationsUser::where('user_id','like',$loginuser->id)->get();
$convUsersIds = $convUsers->modelKeys();

// or if you don't need those models but only their ids:
$convUsersIds = ConversationsUser::where('user_id','like',$loginuser->id)->lists('id');

$events = Events::join('PIVOT_TABLE as ce', 'ce.event_id', '=', 'events.id')
   ->whereIn('ce.conversation_id', $convUsersIds)
   ->get(['events.*']);
```

This will return exactly what you needed.